# How can I make the circuit look like this and add terminal points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, engineering

I'm trying to create a circuit like as shown on the picture. I'm new to tikz and also circuitikz, so I would appreciate some help.
[image]

I tried the following, but I have trouble with adding terminal points at the points of intersection and also adding the ground symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5, european] \draw
(0,0) to[battery=5V] (0,4)
(0,4) -- (4,4)
      to[R, label={$R$}] (4,2) % Resistor
(4,1.7) -- (6,1.7)
(4,2) to[R, label={$R_T$}] (4,0) % Thermistor
(4,0.3) -- (6,0.3)
(4,0) -- (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: replace `--` with `to[short,-o]`

Comment: ...why do you load `siunitx` and  then you do not use it?

Answer (score 6):

[image]I hope this is what you want

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.2, european]
\draw (0,0) to[short, o-] (4,0) to[R, label={$R$}] (4,-3) to[R, label={$R_T$}] (4,-5) to [short, -o] (0,-5);
\draw (4,-3) to[short, *-*] (6,-3) node[anchor=west] {B};
\draw (4,-5) to[short, *-*] (6,-5) node[anchor=west] {GND};
\node at (0,-2.5) {$5V=u_1$};
\node at (6,-4) {$u_2$};
\end{circuitikz}


\end{document}
```

bye

Comment: Well, you've helped me get there :) There's another thing, I'd like to label the battery 'Arduino' and write 5V below it. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: replace \node at (0,-2.5) {$5V=u_1$};
 for  \node[text width=2cm] at (0,-2.5) {Arduino $5V=u_1$};

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that uses named and perpendicular coordinates so that you can change the size of the drawing changing just one parameter at a time.

I am using `siunitx` to typeset the voltage, `l2` to put a two-lines label to the battery and `calc` (preloaded by `circuitikz`) to find coordinates. Notice also that the only needed solder point is the one above the ground symbol (in the case of three wires it's clear that you have a connection).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, EFvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    european]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(gnd)
    to[battery, l2_=\texttt{Arduino} and \SI{5}{V}]
    ++(0,5) % change just this 5 to change height
    -- ++(4,0) coordinate(top) % and this 4 to change width
    to [R=$R$] ($(top)!0.5!(top|-gnd)$) coordinate(tap) % mid point
    to [R=$R_t$] (top|-gnd) node[ground]{} -- (gnd);
    \draw (tap) to[short, -o]  ++(2,0) coordinate(out) node[right]{\texttt{A0-A5}};
    \draw (tap|-gnd) to[short, *-o]  ++(2,0) node[below]{GND};
    \path (out) -- node[midway]{$u_2$} (out|-gnd);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(BTW, I have a wild guess that the R_t over there is a sensor, so you should use `... to[sR=$R_t$] ...` )